# Iteration in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I populate a python dictionary based on few conditions.

My question is:

can we retrieve the dictionary in the same order as it is populated?

```
          questions_dict={}  

              data = str(header_arr[opt]) + str(row)
              questions_dict.update({data : xl_data})
              valid_xl_format = 7
              if (type.lower() == "ma" or type.lower() == "mc"):
                      data = str(header_arr[opt]) + str(row)
                      questions_dict.update({data : xl_data})
                      valid_xl_format = 7
```

After populating if i iterate it is not in the order it is populated

```
     for k in questions_dict:
          logging.debug("%s:%s" %(k,questions_dict[k]))
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep track of the order you populate a dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep track of the order in which a dictionary is populated, you need a type different than `dict` (commonly known as "ordered dict"), such as those from the third-party [odict](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) module, or, if you can upgrade to Python 2.7, [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: What happens when two items map to the same key during insertion?  Does it just remember the last insertion and use that ordering and forget the first insertion ever happened? Update: That solution was easy to find... it retains the original insertion position.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries aren't ordered collections. You have to have some other data to keep track of the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

the reason dictionaries are efficient is that the keys are mapped to objects called hashes and the dictionaries internally stores your values associated to the key's hashes. so when you loop over your entries, this is related to the order of the hashes, not the original keys.